# USB 2 Hub for running USB External Drives

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-storage

I am experiencing an odd problem with using 2 different USB 2.0 Hubs to run a Seagate FreeAgent USB harddrive on.

I'm getting an 'unknown inpage error' (or similar). When i plug in directly to the computer it has no problem. Any ideas what this error is about and how I can get around it? I need to run it on a HUB as im short on USB. Hardware recommendations welcomed!

USB Drive only runs a USB cable. (Does that make it a unpowered drive?)
USB Hub only runs a USB cable. (Does that make it unpowered?)

Comment: Does the hard drive have its own power supply? Is the USB hub powered? I have ran into issues caused by lack of power when using a nonpowered 2.5" USB hard drive and a nonpowered USB hub.

Comment: no. i don't know (it only runs a usb cable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a 2.5" drive?  It possibly needs a powered USB hub.  Is the hub powered?

Comment: how do you know if its powered?

Comment: It will have an AC adapter with it.  Simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would ask: Are you using a powered HUB or not? It could simply be a power problem.

Don't ask me why this might work considering it works when plugged in directly, but others have solved this by doing a couple of things: Running `chkdsk /f` and/or changing the drive letter in the disk management mmc (Of course, you can probably change it back. It won't hurt to try both since they are quick.